# Possibility to modify 1 or 2 arguments from multiple list of arguments in keyword during creation test case in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am curious if it's possible to modify some default argument when I try using following keyword during test case creation. See example below.

```
*** Keywords ***
Open URL With Custom Parameters
     [Arguments]     ${fe}=example.lan   ${be}=https://example.be.lan  ${reminderInterval}=5  ${licence}=default   ${flowId}=7349   ${name}=example    ${cur}=EUR   ${lang}=en
     ...             ${browser}=chrome
     Open Browser    https://${fe}/${name}/debug_index.html?&appsrv=${be}&currency=${cur}&lang=${lang}&reminderInterval=${reminderInterval}&fullscreen=yes&license=${licence}      ${browser}
```

I would like to modify only 2 dedicated arguments e.g. Below doesn't work

```
*** Test Cases ***
Open browser and do sth
    Open URL With Custom Parameters         ${name}=development   ${be}=https://goodday.com`
```

If is possible to change default argument from keyword in different order where is set it in keyword?

I would like to avoid adding all remains parameter to change only 1 or 2 arguments like below:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Open browser and do sth
    Open URL With Custom Parameters         ${fe}=https://development   ${be}=https://goodday3421.com
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just don't use the `${}` around the arguments' names when calling the keyword:

```
Open URL With Custom Parameters         fe=https://development   be=https://goodday3421.com
```